# sftp get command explaination

Tags: get, sftp, remote-access

I found lot of document telling and discussing about how to copy remote folder using sfpt .
but no one have explained up to getting folder on your machine...

even I found it easy up to following command

```
get -r SomeDirectory
```

but after that 
I found long listing of paths (it feel like I am fetching the directory...).
because there was a line retrieving data.....

but after this where that folder is stored ???
where is the fetched folder ??\
do i have to put different command to get this folder to my desktop..

please tell me something is missing ...so that i could not find the fetched folder...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will store the data in the current directory, which starts off wherever you are when running sftp and can be changed with the command "lcd" (means local change directory, similarly to "cd", which is change directory on the remote server).

```
/home/me$ sftp someserver
sftp> get file.txt
```

file.txt will now be in /home/me, because that's where I started the program from.

```
sftp> lcd Desktop
sftp> get file.txt
```

Now, file.txt will be saved to /home/me/Desktop since we changed the local directory to that before getting it.